# Safety net check ok but banking app not working

Tags: rooting, root-access, magisk, safety-net

I'm running magisk latest and have configured it to hide it for the usual suspect apps. 
I also have a custom kernel (Marco) that hides/resets the unlocked boot loader flag.
All tests with safety net apps, Pokemon, Android pay work without any problem, besides two banking apps that reject starting.

How do these banning apps determine root or modifications, while all others cannot?

Comment: They use more than SafetyNet... The exact implementation varies, might check for specific files (does su exist, does Magisk Manager exist, etc) or might just check if /system has EVER been mounted R/W. Is the app logging anything to logcat or elsewhere?

Comment: Nothing in the logs as far as I can see in alogcat. Any other place where it could be? And I always thought the apps are in a sandbox and cannot check arbitrary things like system mounts etc!?

Comment: Generally logging is in the system log or its own directory... Apps are sandboxed from changes or writing anything outside of their own permission context, but they can read a lot of things. Open a terminal in an unrooted device and see what you can do and see, can't do much but a lot you can see.